# How to change path in the server automatically after fixed time interval?

Tags: php, server, filepath

I want a unique link to download a file from link (say `http://arymangupta.hol.es/download/file`)
and after a fixed interval of time (15 days or 10 days) the link should be changed(say `http://arymangupta.hol.es/**AnyRandomString**/file`).

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: You are going to have to explain further about why you want to do this. The second link format you have provided is invalid by the way.

Comment: I just want path to be different maybe like http://(aything)/file.

Comment: You can't do that. You'll have a base domain. The string on that path can be random. For example: `http://aryamangupta.com/YourRandomStringHere`

Comment: yes i was looking for the same , my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't give you the full code, but the procedure is pretty straightforward: first thing, store the original path in a database.

```
+----+-------------+----------------+---------------------+
| id | token       | path_to_file   | date                |
+----+-------------+----------------+---------------------+
| 1  | abcdefghijk | /path/file.pdf | 2016-05-27 00:00:00 |
+----+-------------+----------------+---------------------+
```

Then:

- Create a cronjob to refresh tokens that are expired
- Create a script that given the token will make people able to download the file

To hide the real file path you can use `readfile()` php function.

```
if (file_exists('/path/file.pdf')) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: This process will change the actual path of the file to be download or its just a route @Napolux?

Comment: The path will remain the same. You don't need to change it, and I would avoid moving files around. The download link will change and expire, if you setup it properly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to store path in database, And when you use then get from database.
Second thing if you want change path randomly you should run a cron job for update path in database, whatever you need.